# Screenshot capture of Selenium tests when parallel execution is enabled in Junit5

Tags: selenium, junit5

I am using Page Object Pattern. I have implemented TestWatcher interface in Watcher class to process test case results. In order to take a screenshot for passed/failed test cases I need an instance of WebDriver, driver available . If I declare driver as static then it works well in sequential mode but fails when parallel execution is turned on. Looks like Junit uses single thread for all test methods in single class. If I don't declare driver as static then ExecutionContext object from TestWatcher methods does not give me class name where test method failed. I only able to get classname where @Test is defined. Please suggest if there is a way to achieve it and if I am missing something here. Thanks.

I have tried declaring driver as static and non static.

Answer (score 0):

I removed static WebDriver declaration and ale to get an instance of WebDriver too from ExtensionContext.

```
Field field = context.getRequiredTestInstance().getClass().getDeclaredField("driver");
field.setAccessible(true);
WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) field.get(context.getRequiredTestInstance());
```